# Postman - Using complete response from one request as body of another request

Tags: postman

I have a request were the exact response from one request is the body of another request.

Is there an easy way to store the response from one request to reuse as the body of another request in Postman?

I tried storing the response body in a global variable `customerData` and then having the body of my other request be `{{customerData}}` but this does not work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it a JSON response/payload in the next request? You could try using `sendRequest()` in the tests tab to send the response in another request at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

```
API-1 - Test Tab

//Get the response of first API

var jsonData=JSON.parse(responseBody);

//Convert the JSON response to String

var jsonString=JSON.stringify(jsonData);

//Store in environment variable

pm.environment.set("MyPayLoad", jsonString);



API-2 - Body    
{{MyPayLoad}}
```

This way response from API-1 is passed as payload to API-2

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using the `sendRequest()` function in the `Tests` tab of your first `GET` request. This will send the request and get the data once this has completed, it will then `POST` that same response data to another endpoint.

This is a very basic example that can be added to the `Tests` tab, this can be changed/adapted to your own context:

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'localhost:3000/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify(pm.response.json())
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

This is what it looks like in Postman - I've sent a basic request to the `/get` route and in the `Tests` tab, I'm using that response data as the payload for the `POST` request by inserting the `pm.response.json()`. You can see the request body for the `/post` route has been taken from the first request.

[image: Postman]